# Is forecasting and predictions part of Inferential or Descriptive?

Tags: forecasting, prediction, terminology, descriptive-statistics, inference

Can someone please explain to me which statistics forecasting and predictions are part of? Inferential or Descriptive? I am working on an homework. I was unable to come across the answer in my reading.

Comment: Maybe this is the kind of question whose intention is to encourage you to think about the definitions, rather than look up or request an answer online.

Answer (score 2):

From [What are descriptive and inferential statistics?](http://support.minitab.com/en-us/minitab/17/topic-library/basic-statistics-and-graphs/introductory-concepts/basic-concepts/descriptive-inferential-stats/):

> - Descriptive statistics provide a concise summary of data.
> - Inferential statistics use a random sample of data taken from a population to describe and make inferences about the population

I would say predictions and forecasting use both, depending in the level of knowledge you have. You forecast or predict outside your known data. To do that, you often use descriptive statistics to summarize your data to a line, for instance, and then extrapolate.

However, if you have to choose one, **inferential** is generally the most appropriate. You can look at [Descriptive, Predictive, and Prescriptive Analytics Explained](https://halobi.com/2014/10/descriptive-predictive-and-prescriptive-analytics-explained/), with an additional term, prescriptive:

> - Descriptive Analytics: insight into the past
> - Predictive Analytics: understanding the future
> - Prescriptive Analytics: advise on possible outcomes

However, "predictive" can be understood for interpolation too. For a more solid reading, I suggest: [To Explain or to Predict?](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~aldous/157/Papers/shmueli.pdf) Galit Shmueli, 2010, Statistical Science:

> The purpose of this article is to clarify the distinction between
>   explanatory and predictive modeling, to discuss its sources, and to
>   reveal the practical implications of the distinction to each step in
>   the modeling process

Answer (score 0):

At first blush a forecast could be considered inferential as it infers the future but upon reflection the mean of a series is clearly descriptive and could be the basis of a forecast. If this is so then the mean is both descriptive and a forecast. An ARIMA model more generally describes a series (not uniquely) and is also usable to make a forecast. Thus the forecast can be considered descriptive given the model.

Clearly the person who down-voted this is a statistical novice as no reason was given. That is a shame as we can all learn from constructive criticism even a "self-proclaimed expert" in the field of forecasting.

Comment: If being useful for other purposes makes something inferential, then everything is. I don't object to any suggestions that the categories blur into each other but I think the distinction has more force than you imply. Inferential implies to me going beyond the data at hand, and using a mean as a forecast could be an example with a simple model, future ~ past.

Comment: I didn't downvote. Speculation as to what kind of person it might have been is futile. No criticism made; no reply to be made.

Comment: You are  a fine person ! No question ! .